# Finding the limit of $F(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{|x+2|}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, absolute-value

Let $F(x)=\dfrac{x^2-4}{|x+2|}$ and find the following limits

$(a) \; \; \lim_{x \to -2^-}F(x)=$
$(b) \; \; \lim_{x \to -2^+}F(x)=-4$
$(c) \; \; \lim_{x \to -2}F(x)=DNE$

I substituted $-2$ to find $(b)$ and I guessed on $(c)$. I don't know how to solve for $(a).$ How do I go about solving this? 
I'm also confused a little on how to graph this function.

I did factor it as: $F(x)=\dfrac{(x+2)(x-2)}{(x+2)}$ and then I canceled similar terms.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that the top is $(x+2)(x-2)$.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE Yes, thanks. I factored it and canceled $(x+2)$ with the denominator

Comment: You can't just cancel it, as $\frac{x+2}{|x+2|}\neq 1$. To see this, consider when $x=-3$ and $x=-1$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

$$F(x)=  \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \dfrac{x^2-4}{x+2} & : x \lt -2\\~\\
    \dfrac{x^2-4}{-(x+2)} & : x \gt -2 \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Answer (score 2):

Factor the top as $(x+2)(x-2)$, and notice that as $x \rightarrow -2^{+}$, then the denominator becomes $-(x+2)$.

As $x \rightarrow -2^{-}$, then the denominator becomes $(x+2)$. Now do cancellations, and substitute $x=2$

Comment: Ok, thanks. In the bottom line, do you mean $x \rightarrow -2^{-}$? isn't $x$ approaching negative two?

Comment: @user437158: Yes- sorry for the typo. Let me edit it.